# Can combine five mysql statements into just one statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Can I combine all the five statements into just one statement?

```
update mytable set myfield1 = replace(myfield1, '…' ,'-') ;
update mytable set myfield1 = replace(myfield1, '‖' ,'|') ;
update mytable set myfield1 = replace(myfield1, '”' , '"') ;
update mytable set myfield1 = replace(myfield1, '‘' , '`') ;
update mytable set myfield1 = replace(myfield1, '〃' ,'"') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update mytable set myfield1 =
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(myfield1, '…' ,'-'),
'?' ,'|'),'”' , '"'),'‘' , '`'),'?' ,'"');
```